# Susy Omega problems getting the column widths correct

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass, susy-compass

Having problems trying to get the correct column width across 4 different breakpoints to set as i want.

When i am using span-columns(3, 12) i want the total width at the maximum size there to be 300px with 20px padding between each content. I tried to work it out mathematically to set the widths of each column but it is not working as expected.

Some of my code is:

```
$total-columns: 12;
$column-width: 86.666667px;
$gutter-width: 20px;
$grid-padding: 20px;
$container-width: 1300px;
$container-syle: static;
```

Using the (3, 12) my content block is coming out with a width of 295px. How can i get it to total 300px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do math based on the column-width, you should remove the `$container-width` override. Then the math is pretty simple:

```
3 * $column-width + 2 * $gutter-width = 300px
```

That equation has many possible solutions, depending on the size gutters you want. Clearly you've already done that:

```
3 * 86.666666667px + 2 * 20 ~= 300px
```

or...

```
3 * 90px + 2 * 15px = 300px
```

etc. The only problem with your current setup is that you are overriding the columns-out math with your own `$container-width`.

Comment: This wasn't the EXACT solution but pointed me in the right direction in order to help me solve the issue. Changing the container style to magic also helped to fix the issue. I think my biggest mistake was working from a desktop down grid style, rather than a mobile up.